# How to position my text at the top of a div, instead of the bottom?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Right now it just goes to the bottom. Here's my code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">Machine Learning and Development</h1>
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    <!-- <video autoplay muted src="yoda.mp4" width="700px" align="right" loop preload="metadata"></video> -->
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x400?text=Placeholder+Video" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the text to be at text, but instead it goes to here. (see image):
[image: (see image)]

Link to my HTML and CSS:
https://codeshare.io/5XqAeE

Comment: I don't see the text you're trying to put in. Can you please edit your question to make a working code snippet please.

Comment: can you mention your html and css both for better understanding?

Comment: sure i edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming "Machine Learning and Development" is the text you want at the top above the video, you can use flexbox to achieve this!

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">Machine Learning and Development</h1>
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    <video autoplay muted src="yoda.mp4" width="700px" align="right" loop preload="metadata"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and try removing `text-align: left` from the div holding the video.

Answer (score 0):

> Just see the example below same as yours:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <style>
    img {
      float: left;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center">Machine Learning and Development</h1>
      <div >
        Hello
        <!-- <video autoplay muted src="yoda.mp4" width="700px" align="right" loop preload="metadata"></video> -->
        <img src="your_image_path_will_go_here" style="width:300px;height:300px;margin-left:15px;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```